How to Hide Specific Parts of a Superset Chart in an Embedded Iframe (Without standalone Flag)?
I'm trying to integrate an Apache Superset chart into my web application using an iframe.
When I set standalone=1 in the iframe URL, it shows only the chart, which is great, but I need more flexibility. If I don't use the standalone flag, the entire Superset page is loaded within the iframe (including the full Superset UI like the chart source and header).
My use case requires me to:

Hide specific parts of the Superset UI, such as the chart source panel or header.>
Keep the chart download button visible.

Is there a similar flag (like standalone) or another method to hide specific parts of the Superset window while embedding charts in an iframe?
Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated!
